# getSharedPreferences is returning null on app startup with custom application

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

Currently, I have my own custom `Application` class that I have extended.

```
class CustomApplication : Application() {
    init {
        val x = getSharedPreferences("main", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }
}
```

However, when I run the application, I get the following null pointer error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

How is this possible? I am confused because when I consulted the documentation I see this:

```
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

A method that should never return a null value! Anyone willing to help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the Kotlin lifecycle `init {...}` mixed up with the Android lifecycle `onCreate {...}`.

Posting this trivial solution in case anyone else also stumbles on this in the future.

```
class CustomApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        val x = getSharedPreferences("main", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just commenting here to explain to future readers-  init() is when the object is created.  However for a Context object, there's post init setup that needs to be done to make it work properly (this work is done by the Android Framework).  When this is done, onCreate is called.  Until onCreate is called, whether any other Context functions will work is undefined-  you might get lucky, but I wouldn't count on it.